# How can you remove specific instances of a character, but not all?

Tags: regex, knime

I have a list of names that are separated by a semi-colon:

> BorisovaSvetlana A.;KimHak
>   Joong;PuXiaotao;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;LiuHung-wen*;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?;?

I would like to remove all of the "?;" but only if they occur in that pattern.

I am using KNIME and tried to use `regexReplace($col1$,"[?;]","")` or `regexReplace($col1$,"?;","")` in the String Manipulation node, but all instances of ? and ; are removed.

I want the output to be

> BorisovaSvetlana A.;KimHak Joong;PuXiaotao;LiuHung-wen*

but the actual output is

> BorisovaSvetlana A.KimHak JoongPuXiaotaoLiuHung-wen*

Any guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, as I am new to both KNIME and regex.

Comment: Try `regexReplace($col1$,"([?];)+","")` or  `"([?];){2,}"`

Comment: Or try `regexReplace($col1$,"(;[?])+","")` or  `"(;[?]){2,}"`

Comment: `regexReplace($col1$,"(;[?])+","")` worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the `?` instead of putting it to the alternatives like this: `\?`. As the `\` needs to be escaped because of the quotes, the proper escaping is `\\?` within the String. So the following should work for your request:

```
regexReplace($col1$,"\\?;","")
```

For your input it produces:

```
BorisovaSvetlana A.;KimHak Joong;PuXiaotao;LiuHung-wen*;?
```

[image: Workflow showing the result and the regex]

Comment: Thank you. This would've been perfect if the ";?" at the end of every record could also be eliminated.

Comment: I think what you really wanted was the opposite order of elements, but my answer was following what you have asked for. So the following should perform what you want: `regexReplace($col1$,";\\?","")`

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex: `(?:;\?)+` and replace with empty string to remove the `?;`. Please note that this matches in 478 steps.
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eiO0z6/1)

Then use Regex: `([A-Z][a-z *.-]+)([A-Z][A-Za-z *.-]+)(?=;|$)` and replace with `$1, $2` to get the expected result.
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M6opsF/1)

```
regexReplace(regexReplace($col1$,"(?:;\?)+",""), "([A-Z][a-z *.-]+)([A-Z][A-Za-z *.-]+)(?=;|$)", " $1, $2")
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, but it just eliminated all of the ";"s, but none of the "?"s.